# Write CSV file with one row per each list of lists - python

Tags: python, list, csv, beautifulsoup, scikit-learn

Fom parsing an HTML file with Beautifulsoup (python 2.7), I have the following list of lists structure (and I want it like this in one CSV file row).

```
[[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']], [['gg', 'h'],['ii', 'j']], [['nn', 'o', 'p'], ['qq', 'r', 's']], ['kkkk', 'llll', 'mmmm']]
```

My code is:

```
import csv
with open("profile_test.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(full_profile)

import csv
with open('profile_test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

And the output I am getting is each list within the list of lists in a different row:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']]
[['gg', 'h'],['ii', 'j']]
[['nn', 'o', 'p'], ['qq', 'r', 's']]
['kkkk', 'llll', 'mmmm']
```

I played with the delimitter but did not get any result.

I am new to python and machine learning and I am stuck with formatting my data appropriately.

Thanks for the suggestions.

EDIT

Just for additional clarification, the format I want to get for the data in one row is:

```
[[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']], [['gg', 'h'],['ii', 'j']], [['nn', 'o', 'p'], ['qq', 'r', 's']], ['kkkk', 'llll', 'mmmm']]
```

Comment: so whats your appropriately formatting data?

Comment: What constitutes 1 row?  'aaa' -> 'mmm'?

Comment: Yes, one row = 'aaa' -> 'mmm'

Comment: Thanks @KasraAD, the format I am looking for is the one suggested in the original first structure. All the lists in one row ( 'aaa' -> 'mmm').

Comment: Diego,  I see you saying you want to preserve the list structure.  CSV is simply comma separated values.  its a series of values separated by a comma.  There is no list structure in it.  Can you elaborate more in your question about what you mean by "preserve the original first structure" it doesn't make sense to me.  I don't think others get it either.

Comment: @Kelvin, thank you for the comment. If I consider each list as a value, can't I have all the lists as values separeted by commas in one row?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a single line with all of these letters in it, commas when the letter changes?  Because you've got nested lists at different levels of nesting, I think you're going to have to construct the string to write yourself instead of using the csv package for help.

e.g., if the nesting won't ever get too deep,

```
def big_string(_list):
    try:
        return ','.join(_list)
    except TypeError:
        return ','.join([big_string(thing) for thing in _list])


with open("profile_test.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write(big_string(full_profile))
```

to show what the above function returns,

```
>>> big_string([[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']], [['gg', 'h'],['ii', 'j']], [['nn', 'o', 'p'], ['qq', 'r', 's']], ['kkkk', 'llll', 'mmmm']])
'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,gg,h,ii,j,nn,o,p,qq,r,s,kkkk,llll,mmmm'
```

if you're looking instead for output like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

you can just do:

```
with open("profile_test.csv", "wb") as f:
    for entry in big_string(full_profile).split(','):
        f.write(entry + '\n')
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to run at all.  It does nothing but crash my shell.  Is it python 2 or 3?

Comment: Now it works, and is a better solution than I posted. :)

Comment: @akgill, thank you so much for the suggestion.  What I am looking for is to preserve the nested list structure with all the lists in one row (each list goes between quotes). It should look like the the first structure I presented on this question.

Comment: @Diego, then all you need to do is open the file and do `print(full_profile)`.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
result = []

with open('profile_test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        result.append(row)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code @Alexander Ravikovich; your output prints each list in a different row, what I am looking for is to preserve the original list structure and have it writen and printed out entirely in one row.

Comment: In Python 1.7:

for row in reader:
        print(row),

This is what u looking for? Just print without a newline? Just add comma "," after print()

In Python 3: print(row, end="")

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I want the lists in just one row . Should your code replace the "for row in res" loop above?  Shouldn't I be looking for modifying the "write" portion (creating the CSV file)?

Comment: If u want to WRITE in one row, why to use cvs.writer? Maybe u need just:

f = open('myfile','w')
f.write(str(data))
f.close()

Comment: thank you for the code. It did not write a CSV file (which I am going to use for analysis). Am I missing anything?

Comment: In code that u posted: u are writing to profile_test.csv, and then u are reading from the same file. So, u do writing?! I don't understand what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The writing I posted generated the wrong format (there are four lists of lists and each one is printed out in a separate row). I would like to have everything in one row.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the input. Please let me know if there is anything else I can share that might clarify the problem and its intended solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Diego,

I am still not completely sure what you are going for, but if you want your lists flattened and put together in the highest order list structure you can do something like this:

```
def rws():
    x = [[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']], [['gg', 'h'],['ii', 'j']], [['nn', 'o', 'p'], ['qq', 'r', 's']], ['kkkk', 'llll', 'mmmm']]
    sub_lists = []
    for y in x:
        if hasattr(y[0], '__iter__'): 
            sub_lists.append([i for s in y for i in s] )
        else:
            sub_lists.append(y)
    fin = []
    for l in sub_lists:
        fin.append('|'.join(l))
    print ','.join(fin)
```

It will give you an output of:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|eee|fff
gg|h|ii|j
nn|o|p|qq|r|s
kkkk|llll|mmmm
```

and then :

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|eee|fff,gg|h|ii|j,nn|o|p|qq|r|s,kkkk|llll|mmmm
```

As pointed out, this will not handle deep recursion, it only handles 3 or less.  Also, and more importantly, this is can be comma separated and you can add each one together into one cell.  Is that what you're looking for?

You cannot have any list type structure in a CSV.  That is a clear no.

Comment: Thank you. This is similar somehow to the answer offered by @akgill.  I found another example, I need to get something like this:     category,runners_up,winner,category_url  ->  Best wine shop\ ,"[u'In Fine Spirits', u'Life s a Cabernet']",[u'Lush Wine & Spirits'],http://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-wine-shop/BestOf?oid=4088469
I got this from a CSV file that was the result of a Beautifulsoup parse just like I am doing. What do you think?